# How do I retain selected option after submit?

Tags: html, django

Is there a way to retain the selected option from a drop down list that is using a for loop?

views.py:

```
...

queryC = request.GET.get('clientList', '')
queryT = request.GET.get('topicList', '')
topicList = Topic.objects.all().order_by('Name')
clientList = ClientDetail.objects.all().order_by('Client_name')

...

return render(request, 'app/search_es20.html', {
    "responses": responses,
    "query": q,
    "queryR": queryR,
    "noOfResults": resultsCount,
    "username": username,
    "topicList": topicList,
    "clientList": clientList,
    "queryC": queryC,
    "queryT": queryT,
})
```

html:

```
Topic
   <select name="topicList">
       <option value="empty"></option>
       {% for element in topicList %}
       <option value={{element.Name}}>{{ element.Name }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
   </select>

Client
   <select name="clientList">
       <option value="empty"></option>
       {% for element in clientList %}
       <option value={{element.Client_name}}>{{ element.Client_name }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
   </select>
```

I have tried using IF statements but it's not doing it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access on context (or on request) to the selected value, then you can do something like this:

```
<option value={{element.Client_name}} {% if element.Client_name == some_var %} selected {% endif %}>{{ element.Client_name }}</option>
```